# BluemixのWebインターフェースの日本語化

Tags: node.js, bluemix

Bluemixで開発をしています
メニューなどWebの画面表示が英語なのですが言語設定変更はどこでできるのでしょうか

Answer (score 2, accepted):

お疲れ様です。
BluemixのWeb UIの表示言語は、お使いのWebブラウザの設定に依存します。
ブラウザ側で言語を設定してください。